# How to make a content scroll bar use the main viewport scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position my layout so that the header and sidebar are fixed and don't get pushed down when the content div is filled up, I only want the content div to be scrollable and I have that working but the scroll bar is displayed as part of the content div but I would like it to use the main browser window scroll bar, is this possible?

Here is my example of what I am trying to do:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header{
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

#sideBar {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: grey;
  width: 12%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #d0cfd4;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.footer ul {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 0.1em;
  border-top: 1px solid #d0cfd4;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <header>
    <p>Header</p>
  </header>

  <main>

    <div id="sideBar">
      <!-- Main Links to stay at the top -->
      <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Footer Links to stay at the bottom of sidebar -->
      <div class="footer">
        <ul>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
      <h1>Content!</h1>
    </div>

  </main>

</html>
```

You can see that the content is scrollable but the scrollbar is not using the viewports main scroll bar, I would like it to default to the main viewport scroll bar but still keep the header and sidebar fixed the way they are.

Nice example of what I am trying to do: [image] - From @Titulum

Comment: Just to be sure, [this](https://i.imgur.com/lFGPpyt.png) is what you want?

Comment: @Titulum Yes that is what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it should be enough just to set the header's `position:` to `fixed` or `sticky`. [Here is an example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) and [here is another one](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_sidebar.asp). Hope that helps. First I just didn't get what you mean at all. I thought that your problem was the sidebar footer.

Comment: My goal is to have the footer on the sidebar so that the main content can take up the main area and scroll down but I always want the sidebar to be in view. If you take a look at @Titulum comment, they made a nice image example.

Comment: I should have made an image example like @Titulum did, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Erdss4 completely changed my post.

Comment: Thank you, setting the header to `sticky` works but not with the sidebar, it still scrolls with the main content?

Comment: I'll add another example to my post.